# Inserting block above H1 (Title) in Wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am trying to insert a block above the Title in Wordpress using hook `add_action` in `functions.php`. But it displays above all blocks, even above the main menu.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_function_name');

function my_function_name(){
  ?>
    CODE OF BLOCK
  <?php
};
```

How to modify the code to make the block displayed above the H1 (title of the article)?

Comment: Why don't you just modify the template? It's faster, easier and less error prone.

Comment: cant you modify your header.php?

Comment: Because there are several different header files: header-classic, header-inline, header-overlay, header-side, etc. I just want to create universal method for all headers.

Comment: You can't do what you want the way you are going.

Comment: That filter is for the `<head>` element, not your page header.

Comment: Unless your theme/template provides you with a hook before printing the title, you wont be able to do it this way. Easier to edit your headers and add the hook yourself.

Comment: then you can use jquery to append a div above it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using this code:

`add_action('presscore_before_main_container', 'my_function_name');
function my_function_name(){
?> 
CODE OF BLOCK
<?php 
}`